# How to find xpath in label class?

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

Can someone assist, I need to identify the xpath that's inside label class for the last ticket-type. The .html code is as below.

```
<div class="vertical-accordion">
<ul id="accordion-5" class="accordion">
<li class="open-li">
<a class="toggle-link open" href="#">
<span>Tickets on your smart card</span>
</a>
<div class="accordion-drop" style="display: block;">
<ul>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<label class="ticket-type">megarider</label>
<label class="validity"> (7 day: 16 June to 22 June 2016 ) </label>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</article>
```

Comment: Means you need this `<label class="ticket-type">megarider</label>` or something else?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find the last ticket-type, I assume that there are multiple ticket type...

You didn't provide a lot of HTML, I'll answer with that assumption :

`//label[@class='ticket-type'][last()]`

Hope it'll help !

Comment: To add to Nicolas, you can learn more about it here: http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/choosing-effective-xpath/

Comment: And in addition to virus' comment, I would recommend to use relative xpath whenever it's possible. And of course, if the answer helped you, don't forget to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this xpath to find the element in your example:

`//label[@class='ticket-type'][1]`

Comment: @Saurabh - I need to catch the last item of the ticket type. I tried this code but not working:  String LastProd = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//label[@class='ticket-type']/label)[last()]")).getText()

Comment: Don't add the `/label` to the end. See @Nicolas G's answer, that should work.

Comment: Hi - this line //label[@class='ticket-type'][last()] didn't work for me. I have provided more of .html code. Please have a look and let me know of any other possible solution. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Open up this page using Chrome, Hit F12 Developer tools, Inspect the element, find the label in the F12 window (Elements Tab) right click on the label tag and select Copy -> Copy XPath

Comment: -this is not the right answer. I'm looking for more generic solution for catching the last of the ticket-type as shown in my html provided above. //label[@class='ticket-type'][1] didn't work either.